# $\{x\times (1/x)| 0<x\leq 1\}$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: general-topology

The background is Munkres's topology says:

Every closed interval in $\mathbb{R}$ is compact.

and

A subspace A of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is compact if and only if it is closed and is bounded in the square (or Eucliean) metric.

followed by two counter examples which confuse me:
$$
A=\{x\times (1/x)\;| \;0<x\leq 1\}
$$
is closed in $\mathbb{R}^2$ (**why?**) and not bounded (easy to see).

$$
S=\{x\times \sin(1/x)\;| \;0<x\leq 1\}
$$
is NOT closed in $\mathbb{R}^2$ (**why?**) and bounded (easy to see).

Comment: Consider their complement. In one every point outside $A$ is exterior; in $S$, every point $(0,c)$ ($-1\le c\le1$) is outside but not exterior to $S$.

Comment: thank you! could you please elaborate your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(a,b) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ be in the closure of $A$. There exists a sequence $(x_n)$ of elements of $(0,1]$ such that
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \left( x_n, \frac{1}{x_n} \right) = (a,b)$$

Therefore,
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} x_n = a, \quad \quad \text{ and } \lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \frac{1}{x_n}  =b$$

so $a \neq 0$ (otherwise $1/x_n$ would tend to $+\infty$), so $a \in (0, 1]$ and $b=1/a$. Therefore
$$(a,b)= \left( a, \frac{1}{a} \right) \in A$$

So every point of the closure of $A$ belongs to $A$, so $A$ is closed.

$S$ is not closed because
$$(0,1) = \lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \left( \frac{1}{\frac{\pi}{2}+2n\pi}, \sin \left(\frac{\pi}{2}+2n\pi\right)\right)$$

but $(0,1) \notin S$.

Answer (score 1):

Well... let's check. Let $y=(y_1,y_2)\in \mathbb{R}^2\setminus A$.

If $y_1\not \in [0,1]$, then let $\varepsilon=\frac{\min\{|y_1|,|y_1-1|\}}{2}$. Then, $B(y,\varepsilon)\cap A=\emptyset$, since $B(y,\varepsilon)$ does not contain any element with first coordinate in $[0,1]$.

If $y_1\in (0,1]$, apply continuity of $x\mapsto 1/x$ to get some $\epsilon>0$ such that $|x-y_1|<\epsilon$ implies $|\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{y_1}|\leq \frac{|\frac{1}{y_1}-y_2|}{2}$. Again $B(y,\varepsilon)\cap A=\emptyset$.

If, finally, $y_1=0$, use that $\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{1}{x}=\infty$ to pick some $\varepsilon$ such that $x\in (0,\varepsilon)$ implies $\frac{1}{x}\geq 2|y_2|+10^4$. Again, $B(y,\varepsilon)\cap A=\emptyset$.

Since $y$ was arbitrary, we conclude that $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus A$ is open.

To see that $S$ is not closed, let $x_n=\frac{1}{2\pi n}$ and note that $(x_n,\sin(1/x_n))=(\frac{1}{2\pi n},0),$ which converges to $(0,0)\not \in S$. Hence, $S$ is not closed.

Comment: thank you very much for the answer! I understand the second proof, as it is based on "a subset of a topological space is closed if it contains all its limit points". But I cannot see which theorem the first proof is finally based on.

Comment: It's not based on any theorem? I'm just checking the definition of openness.